# Massive MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database-design, query-optimization

I'm making a website which requires an absolutely massive mysql database, with potentially millions or even billions of rows in a single table.

The table structure is two "text" fields.

How can this be optimized for querying? I want to be able to fetch a single row at a time only, but as quickly as possible.

One field might have slightly longer text chunks, but the other one will have a relatively short one at all times, and any row selection will be done based on the other one.

Alternatively, is there a better way to store this many values?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: "or even billions of rows in a single table" -  "The table structure is two "text" fields."  - sounds like a warehouse

Comment: What do you want to store, and what exactly are you using it for? Maybe if we knew more context we could help more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in essence, to fetch a row you will be doing something like:

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE col1 = "someText";`

Is that correct?  If so, then the only optimization you can really apply is to add an index on `col1`.

But, does your data naturally segregate in some way?  Are there any logical groups that exist?  If so you could break it down into multiple tables and distribute the data between them.

Or if not then you could always segregate based upon something like the first character in `col1` assuming that the values here will always be in some reasonable range (like `[a-z]`).  Then you could do things like:

`SELECT * FROM myTable_s WHERE col1 = "someText";`
`SELECT * FROM myTable_o WHERE col1 = "otherText";`

Having multiple small tables and choosing between them programmatically will be faster than having a single large table that has everything in it, for very large data sets.

Comment: That's good, I might go for that.

Answer (score 0):

the only way to optimize it is to not use text but varchar[size] for your columns
but this is possible only if size has a rezonable limit (if it is to big indexing won't be to as effective, and varchar[size] has a fixed size unlike text)

of course the best way would be to use something short for searching, with a table with millions table I can only recommend using int as primary key even if this means you have to add a new column

Answer (score 0):

I'm far from an expert when it comes to databases but if you're selecting single rows based on a single field, I'd assume that field might be unique? It might be a good idea to create a hash index on that field although I'm not sure how well that will hold up once with many millions rows.